# How can i use VBA Code to Copy and Paste Specific Cells if Condition is Met in two or more worksheets to different areas of another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a little more help please. I was here a month ago a RiskyPenguin gave me a great bit of code. I would like to add to this.

This is the part that works:
So if the "invoice" spreadsheet (sheet 5), if cell G4 (for example is I111) matches any of the data in the first column of the "income" spreadsheet (sheet 1) (starting at row 6) then the corresponding data in columns 2 3, 8 & 9 will copy over to the "invoice" spreadsheet in columns 2, 3, 4 & 5 (starting at row 13).

```vb
Sub FindAndCopyData2()
    Dim shData As Worksheet, shReport As Worksheet
    Set shData = Sheet1
    Set shReport = Sheet6
    
    Dim strInvoceNumber As String
    strInvoceNumber = shReport.Cells(4, "E").Value
    
    Dim intLastRow As Integer
    intLastRow = shData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim intReportRow As Integer
    intReportRow = 13
    
    shReport.Range("B13:E20").ClearContents
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To intLastRow
        If shData.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = strInvoceNumber Then
            shReport.Cells(intReportRow, 2).Value2 = shData.Cells(i, 3).Value2
            shReport.Cells(intReportRow, 3).Value2 = shData.Cells(i, 4).Value2
            shReport.Cells(intReportRow, 4).Value2 = shData.Cells(i, 8).Value2
            shReport.Cells(intReportRow, 5).Value2 = shData.Cells(i, 9).Value2
            
            intReportRow = intReportRow + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I would then like to (hopefully using the same search)

Take the "invoice" spreadsheet (sheet 5), if cell G4 (for example is I111) matches any of the data in the second column of the "expenses" spreadsheet (sheet 2) (starting at row 11) then the corresponding data in columns 3, 5, & 7 will copy over to the "invoice" spreadsheet in columns 2, 4 & 6 (starting at row 13).

Is this possible or does it have to be a separate piece of programming?
Many Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be possible? What specific problem you're facing or error you're receiving?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to incorporate the new requirement into the old programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this could be useful for others I made a function out of it and refactored the initial code to handle the copy in memory. I setup your first lookup so you just need to edit the variables to get your second lookup:

```
Option Explicit
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''Main Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Sub main()
        'Set some vars
        Dim sourceArr, targetArr, sourceCls, targetCls, sourceStartRw As Long, targetStartRw As Long, dict As Object, j As Long, sourceLookupCl As Long, Matchkey As Long
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''Lookup 1
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Matchkey = Sheet5.Range("G4").Value2 'lookupKey
        sourceCls = Split("2,3,8,9 ", ",") 'Columns to copy from
        targetCls = Split("2,3,4,5", ",") 'Columns to copy to
        sourceStartRw = 6
        targetStartRw = 13
        sourceLookupCl = 1 'matching column
        
        'get data in memory = array
        sourceArr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2
        
        'call our function
        targetArr = reorder(sourceArr, sourceCls, targetCls, sourceStartRw, sourceLookupCl, Matchkey)
        
        'dump to sheet
        With Sheet5
            .Range(.Cells(targetStartRw, 1), .Cells(UBound(targetArr) + targetStartRw - 1, UBound(targetArr, 2))).Value2 = targetArr
        End With
        
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''Lookup 2 => change source and target cols to your need
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Matchkey = Sheet5.Range("G4").Value2
        sourceCls = Split("2,3,8,9 ", ",")
        targetCls = Split("2,3,4,5", ",")
        sourceStartRw = 6
        targetStartRw = 13 'must be the same as previous lookup if you want to keep the targetArr from previous lookups
        sourceLookupCl = 1
        
        'get data in memory = array
        sourceArr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2
        
        'call our function keeping the data from the first lookup
        targetArr = reorder(sourceArr, sourceCls, targetCls, sourceStartRw, sourceLookupCl, Matchkey, targetArr)
        
        'dump to sheet
        With Sheet5
            .Range(.Cells(targetStartRw, 1), .Cells(UBound(targetArr) + targetStartRw - 1, UBound(targetArr, 2))).Value2 = targetArr
        End With
    End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''Supporting function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Private Function reorder(sourceArr, sourceCls, targetCls, sourceStartRw As Long, sourceLookupCl As Long, Matchkey As Long, Optional targetArr) As Variant
        Dim dict As Object, j As Long
        'if the target array overlaps the previous lookups pass it to the function
        If IsMissing(targetArr) Then
            ReDim targetArr(1 To UBound(sourceArr), 1 To UBound(sourceArr, 2))
        End If
        
        'build a dict to compare quickly
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create dictionary lateB
        For j = 1 To UBound(sourceArr) 'traverse source
            dict(sourceArr(j, sourceLookupCl)) = Empty
        Next j
        
        'check if key exists in dict and copy data
        Dim i As Long, ii As Long ': ii = 1
        If dict.Exists(Matchkey) Then
            For j = sourceStartRw To UBound(sourceArr)
                For i = 1 To UBound(sourceArr, 2)
                    If i = sourceCls(ii) Then
                        targetArr(j - sourceStartRw + 1, targetCls(ii)) = sourceArr(j, i)
                        ii = IIf(ii < UBound(sourceCls), ii + 1, ii)
                    End If
                Next i
                ii = 0
            Next j
        End If
        
        reorder = targetArr
    End Function
```